# Two Brachos before shema and one after in the morning, and two before and after in the evening

Tags: shema, tractate-brachot

In the first Gemara of Brachos, the gemara quotes a 'seifa' that says:

THE MORNING SHEMA IS PRECEDED BY TWO BRACHOS AND FOLLOWED BY ONE. THE EVENING SHEMA IS PRECEDED BY TWO BRACHOS AND FOLLOWED BY TWO"

What brachos are referred to in this quote?

Comment: The gemara usually calls anything taught afterwards in the same chapter a "seifa."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Mishnah in Berachos (Perek 1:4)

The Brachos are as follows:

**Morning Shema:**

1. The first Bracha starts with "Baruch ata...Yotzer Ohr Uvoreh Chosech..." and ends with "Baruch ata...Yotzer Hameorot" (at the end of "es shem")
2. The Second Bracha Starts with "Ahavas olam ahavtanu..." I believe the exact wording may vary by Nusach, and ends with "Baruch ata...Yotzer Hameorot" followed directly by Shema.
3. The After Bracha starts with "Emes V'yatziv" and ends with "Ga'al Yisrael".

**Evening Shema:**

1. The first Bracha starts with "Baruch ata...asher bidvaro maariv aravim..." and ends with "Baruch ata...hamaariv aravim"
2. The second Bracha starts with "Ahavas olam.." and ends with "Baruch ata...ohev amo yisrael" followed directly by shema.
3. The first after Bracha starts with "emes ve'emuna" and ends with "Baruch ata...ga'al yisrael"
4. The Second after Bracha starts with "Hashkivenu..." and ends with "Baruch ata...Shomer es amo Yisroel La'ad" (I believe there is a difference here depending on your nusach.)

Note:
The reason the second Bracha in both the Morning shema (before) and the evening shema (before and after) do not start with "Baruch ata..." is because they are "Brachos hasmuchos l'chaverta" since the previous Brachos ended with "Baruch ata..." these do not start with "Baruch ata"

The same applies for Brachot that start right after the Shema. (they don't start with "Baruch ata..." but they are still considered their own Bracha)

Comment: +1 But not everyone agrees that the brachot "Emes ve..." lack an opening because they are semuchot to the earlier brachot.

Comment: @DoubleAA Notice I have not made any mention of the opening words of the Bracha directly after Shema. After further research I have found that this Bracha too is considered Smucha L'chaverta, even though Shema technically interrupts between the previous bracha; but since emes and vyatziv are said smucha one to another, this Bracha is nevertheless considered smucha. Where did you see otherwise?